# Child processes in NodeJS: 100 data streams + math calculations

Tags: node.js, child-process

Lets say, 
you got 100 data streams.
Each holding about 20.000 values..

Whenever a stream receives new values, the stream has do some basic calculations over his past 20.000 values.. No real heavy calculations, but still a few things like percentages etc.

I could manage it really well, by keeping it optimised.. But at the end, this is getting heavy for a single nodeJS thread, so I am looking to divide workload over multiple processes.

Only thing is, i'm pretty stuck!.

What would be the best way to do this:

**1: Start 100 new node instances, a.k 'cluster'
But I think this would cause massive overhead, because they all have the same dependencies.. To much for doing just some calculations.**

**2: Create child_processes that never dies and have there own data stream instance, simple only giving it the 'newest' records.. The process its selfs holds all the past records, not the 'main' process..**

**3: Only place calculations inside a seperate thread, and constantly pass it the 20.000 records to do its calculations on.. But this is also putting a massive pressure on the data intensity I would say??**

***4: Webworkers..??***

It has to be real good performance, because on init of the program, all 100 streams get 5000 records of 'history' to pre-calculate.. This takes about 30 seconds when done in a single thread (read: to long)

Thanks!!

Comment: Short story: benchmark.  Find out what your bottleneck is, and how much more of it you would need before trying to solve the issue.  What is node doing in those 30 seconds?

Comment: Node has to do a lot of looping, lots and lots of looping, over 500.000 records (100 * 5000).. Setting averages etc, dividing, basic math stuff.. So I thought it would be perfect for each data stream into each own thread... Cause the problem is obvious looping and calculating...